# JAXB unmarshal returning null values for attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Can you please diagnose why my code prints out [null, null, null, null]:

```
Unmarshaller m = JAXBContext.newInstance(Roles.class).createUnmarshaller();
Roles root = m.ummarshal(new FileReader("test.xml"));
System.out.println(root);
```

I tried debugging in eclipse but breakpoints at the setters and getters don't hit

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Roles>
 <Ele Id="1" Value="Yes"/>
 <Ele Id="2" Value="Yes"/>
 <Ele Id="3" Value="No"/>
 <Ele Id="4" Value="Yes"/>
</Roles>
```

**Roles.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Roles")
public class Roles {
 private List<Ele> EleList;
 public Roles() {super();}

 @XmlElement(name="Ele")
 public List<Ele> getEleList() {return EleList;}
 public void setEleList(List<Ele> EleList) {this.EleList = EleList;}
 public String toString() {return EleList.toString();}
}
```

**Ele.java**

```
public class Ele {

 @XmlAttribute
 private String Id;

 @XmlAttribute
 private String Value;

 public Ele(){super();}

 public String getId() {return Id;}
 public void setId(String id) {Id = id;}
 public String getValue() {return Value;}
 public void setValue(String value) {Value = value;}

 public String toString() { if(Id == null || Value == null) return null; else return Id + Value;}
}
```

Comment: In that case, you can post that as an answer and accept in several days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

You need to write: `@XmlAttribute(name="Id")` & `@XmlAttribute(name="Value")` above the `getId()` and `getValue()` in place of just `@XmlAttribute`. The identifier names are not picked up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are not following Java naming conventions: variables need to start with lowercase letter. If you used lowercase variable and element names, it would work without listing the names explicitly:

```
@XmlAttribute
private String id;

public String getId() {return id;}
public void setId(String id) {id = id;}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Roles>
 <Ele id="1" value="Yes"/>
 <Ele id="2" value="Yes"/>
 <Ele id="3" value="No"/>
 <Ele id="4" value="Yes"/>
</Roles>
```